# Apache beam in Dataflow getting errors related to generator object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I am trying to create my first pipleine in dataflow, I have the same code runnign when i execute using the interactive beam runner but on dataflow I get all sort of errors, which are not making much sense to me.

I am getting json from pub sub which is of the following format.

```
{"timestamp":1589992571906,"lastPageVisited":"https://kickassdataprojects.com/simple-and-complete-tutorial-on-simple-linear-regression/","pageUrl":"https://kickassdataprojects.com/","pageTitle":"Helping%20companies%20and%20developers%20create%20awesome%20data%20projects%20%7C%20Data%20Engineering/%20Data%20Science%20Blog","eventType":"Pageview","landingPage":0,"referrer":"direct","uiud":"31af5f22-4cc4-48e0-9478-49787dd5a19f","sessionId":322371}
```

Here is the code of my pipeline.

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import apache_beam as beam
#from apache_beam.runners.interactive import interactive_runner
#import apache_beam.runners.interactive.interactive_beam as ib
import google.auth
from datetime import timedelta
import json
from datetime import datetime
from apache_beam import window
from apache_beam.transforms.trigger import AfterWatermark, AfterProcessingTime, AccumulationMode, AfterCount
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import StandardOptions
import argparse
import logging
from time import mktime

def setTimestamp(elem):
     from apache_beam import window
     yield window.TimestampedValue(elem, elem['timestamp'])

def createTuples(elem):
     yield (elem["sessionId"], elem)

class WriteToBigQuery(beam.PTransform):
  """Generate, format, and write BigQuery table row information."""
  def __init__(self, table_name, dataset, schema, project):
    """Initializes the transform.
    Args:
      table_name: Name of the BigQuery table to use.
      dataset: Name of the dataset to use.
      schema: Dictionary in the format {'column_name': 'bigquery_type'}
      project: Name of the Cloud project containing BigQuery table.
    """
    # TODO(BEAM-6158): Revert the workaround once we can pickle super() on py3.
    #super(WriteToBigQuery, self).__init__()
    beam.PTransform.__init__(self)
    self.table_name = table_name
    self.dataset = dataset
    self.schema = schema
    self.project = project

  def get_schema(self):
    """Build the output table schema."""
    return ', '.join('%s:%s' % (col, self.schema[col]) for col in self.schema)

  def expand(self, pcoll):
    return (
        pcoll
        | 'ConvertToRow' >>
        beam.Map(lambda elem: {col: elem[col]
                               for col in self.schema})
        | beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
            self.table_name, self.dataset, self.project, self.get_schema()))


class ParseSessionEventFn(beam.DoFn):
  """Parses the raw game event info into a Python dictionary.
  Each event line has the following format:
    username,teamname,score,timestamp_in_ms,readable_time
  e.g.:
    user2_AsparagusPig,AsparagusPig,10,1445230923951,2015-11-02 09:09:28.224
  The human-readable time string is not used here.
  """
  def __init__(self):
    # TODO(BEAM-6158): Revert the workaround once we can pickle super() on py3.
    #super(ParseSessionEventFn, self).__init__()
    beam.DoFn.__init__(self)

  def process(self, elem):
          #timestamp = mktime(datetime.strptime(elem["timestamp"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").utctimetuple())
          elem['sessionId'] = int(elem['sessionId'])
          elem['landingPage'] = int(elem['landingPage'])
          yield elem

class AnalyzeSessions(beam.DoFn):
  """Parses the raw game event info into a Python dictionary.
  Each event line has the following format:
    username,teamname,score,timestamp_in_ms,readable_time
  e.g.:
    user2_AsparagusPig,AsparagusPig,10,1445230923951,2015-11-02 09:09:28.224
  The human-readable time string is not used here.
  """
  def __init__(self):
    # TODO(BEAM-6158): Revert the workaround once we can pickle super() on py3.
    #super(AnalyzeSessions, self).__init__()
    beam.DoFn.__init__(self)

  def process(self, elem, window=beam.DoFn.WindowParam):
          sessionId = elem[0]
          uiud = elem[1][0]["uiud"]
          count_of_events = 0
          pageUrl = []
          window_end = window.end.to_utc_datetime()
          window_start = window.start.to_utc_datetime()
          session_duration = window_end - window_start
          for rows in elem[1]:
             if rows["landingPage"] == 1:
                    referrer = rows["refererr"]
             pageUrl.append(rows["pageUrl"])       

          return {
             "pageUrl":pageUrl,
             "eventType":"pageview",
             "uiud":uiud,
             "sessionId":sessionId,
             "session_duration": session_duration,
              "window_start" : window_start
               }

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--topic', type=str, help='Pub/Sub topic to read from')
    parser.add_argument(
          '--subscription', type=str, help='Pub/Sub subscription to read from')
    parser.add_argument(
          '--dataset',
          type=str,
          required=True,
          help='BigQuery Dataset to write tables to. '
          'Must already exist.')
    parser.add_argument(
          '--table_name',
          type=str,
          default='game_stats',
          help='The BigQuery table name. Should not already exist.')
    parser.add_argument(
          '--fixed_window_duration',
          type=int,
          default=60,
          help='Numeric value of fixed window duration for user '
          'analysis, in minutes')
    parser.add_argument(
          '--session_gap',
          type=int,
          default=5,
          help='Numeric value of gap between user sessions, '
          'in minutes')
    parser.add_argument(
          '--user_activity_window_duration',
          type=int,
          default=30,
          help='Numeric value of fixed window for finding mean of '
          'user session duration, in minutes')
    args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    session_gap = args.session_gap * 60
    options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    # Set the pipeline mode to stream the data from Pub/Sub.
    options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True

    options.view_as( StandardOptions).runner= 'DataflowRunner'
    options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=options)
    lines = (p
                | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
              subscription="projects/phrasal-bond-274216/subscriptions/rrrr")
             | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
             | beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x))
             | beam.ParDo(ParseSessionEventFn())
             )

    next = ( lines
                | 'AddEventTimestamps' >> beam.Map(setTimestamp)
                | 'Create Tuples' >> beam.Map(createTuples)
                | beam.Map(print) 
                | 'Window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.Sessions(15))
                | 'group by key' >> beam.GroupByKey()          
                | 'analyze sessions' >> beam.ParDo(AnalyzeSessions())         
                | 'WriteTeamScoreSums' >> WriteToBigQuery(
                args.table_name,
               {

               "uiud":'STRING',
               "session_duration": 'INTEGER',
               "window_start" : 'TIMESTAMP'
                          },
                options.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions).project)
             )

    next1 = ( next
             | 'Create Tuples' >> beam.Map(createTuples)
             | beam.Map(print) 

             )

    result = p.run()
#    result.wait_till_termination()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
  run()
```

In the following code, I get the following error 'generator' object is not subscriptable, when I try to create tuples in my pipeline. I get it using yield is creating the generator object, even return doesn't work it just beaks my pipeline.

```
apache_beam.coders.coder_impl.SequenceCoderImpl.get_estimated_size_and_observables File "sessiontest1.py", line 23, in createTuples TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable [while running 'generatedPtransform-148']
```

Here is the code I use to execute the pipeline.

```
python3 sessiontest1.py     --project phrasal-bond-xxxxx     --region us-central1     --subscription projects/phrasal-bond-xxxxx/s
ubscriptions/xxxxxx     --dataset sessions_beam     --runner DataflowRunner     --temp_location gs://webevents/sessions --service_account_email-xxxxxxxx-
compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks guys, again first time working on dataflow, so not sure what I am missing here.

Other errors I was getting before that are sorted now:-

a) I get the error that widow is not defined from the line name beam.Map(lambda elem: window.TimestampedValue(elem, elem['timestamp'])) .

If I go beam.window then it says beam is not defined, according to me beam should be provided by dataflow,

```
NameError: name 'window' is not defined [while running 'generatedPtransform-3820']
```

You just need to import the modules in the function itself.

Comment: Can you use **beam.window** inside your lambda function and inside the WindowInto() metod? As follows: `beam.Map(lambda elem: beam.window.TimestampedValue(..` and `.WindowInto(beam.window.Sessions(..` as stated in the documentation, [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/). Did it work?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes Thanks for the input I got that part working, but I am running to a different issue now, 'generator' object is not subscriptable , this happens when I try to create tuples so that I can group them by key. I changed my code above so that you can see the changes. Any idea why that maybe happending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a `'generator' object is not subscriptable` error on createTuples indicates that when you try to do `elem["sessionID"]`, the elem is already a generator. The previous transform you do is setTimestamp, which is also using `yield` and therefore outputting a generator that gets passed as the element to createTuples.

The solution here is to implement setTimestamp and createTuples with `return` instead of `yield`. Return the element you want to receive in the following transform.

Comment: TL;DR use `return` for `Map/MapTuple` and yield for `FlatMap/ParDo`.

Answer (score 0):

You should set save_main_session = True in your code. ( try to uncomment that line in your code). See more about NameError here : https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq

Comment: Thanks for the input I got that part working, but I am running to a different issue now, 'generator' object is not subscriptable , this happens when I try to create tuples so that I can group them by key. I changed my code above so that you can see the changes. Any idea why that maybe happending.?